# Can I write "cupcake sprinkle"? -- Google searches are bringing up "sprinkle cupcakes"

Tags: word-choice

I'm writing a text where the object of the text is the sprinkle on top of the cupcake, "cupcake sprinkle". But I've searched it and it all turns up "sprinkle cupcakes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use quotes if you want to impose a specific order on a Google search.

"Cupcake sprinkle" [returns more than 20000 results](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22cupcake+sprinkle%22).

*Sprinkle* can be used both as a noun (to designate the candies you put on top of cakes) and as a verb (to designate the act of sprinkling the candies).

**EDIT**: as psmears points out the plural form *sprinkles* is more commonly used.

Comment: I believe "sprinkles" is more common: note that nearly all the results on that Google search are for "cupcake sprinkle + <noun>" - "cupcake sprinkle party", "... candies", "... ring", "... club", "... shirt", "... bottle cap", whereas if you search for [cupcake sprinkles](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22cupcake+sprinkle%22#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=%22cupcake+sprinkles%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=93f76488ed786687&biw=1143&bih=682) the results are referring to the stuff itself :)

Comment: @psmears: good point, I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 7):

If you're talking about the little sugary tidbits that are commonly sprinkled over cakes, ice cream and so on, then that's usually called [sprinkles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprinkles) (or *hundreds and thousands* or a few other names).

If you want to refer to this sort of confectionery, specifically intended for cupcakes, then you can say *cupcake sprinkles*. But you might not need to, because the word *sprinkles* already has that connotation.

Comment: Regional note: People in New England call them "jimmies"; I could never get used to that.

Comment: @Robusto: My sister confused the staff in an ice cream parlor in Canada when she asked for her ice cream to be topped with hundreds and thousands: "Hundreds and thousands of *what*?! Oh, you mean *sprinkles*!"