# What kind of rain is "sprinkles"?

Tags: adjectives, american-english, british-english

It appears that MSN Weather has chosen an amusing adjective (from my British point of view) for the weather today:

[image: Sprinkles]

I'm assuming the precipitation (sadly) won't contain any hundreds-and-thousands. To a British person, what is this equivalent to: drizzle, mizzle or deluge?

Comment: What are "hundreds-and-thousands"?

Comment: First time I've seen it too. I suppose it's what our meteos call spits and spots.

Comment: Hundreds-and-thousands are a sweet. Think sprinkles on a cupcake.

Comment: First time I'd heard it was here: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/22686/2007  Ah, the things you learn

Comment: *Hundreds-and-thousands* aren't really "a sweet". They're what Brits call the cake topping @Dusty linked to. In the UK, *sprinkles* are usually *salad sprinkles* (toasted seeds, bacon-flavoured crumbs, etc.) scattered on/in green salad.

Comment: @Fumble: In London, I only come across *sprinkles* at an ice-cream van, where they are *hundreds-and-thousands* or something similar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use of *[sprinkle](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/sprinkle_2)* to describe a light fall of rain is fine in both varieties.
*Sprinkling* is also used in AmE.

Comment: More than a drizzle, less than light rain.

Comment: Never heard that before (anywhere). I speak AmE. Sounds vaguely...wrong.

Comment: I speak AmE, and have definitely heard the verb (i.e., *it's sprinkling*). The noun sounds less familiar.

Comment: I have heard it quite a bit in Southern California, but not on the East Coast. My theory is that Californians are more accustomed to having yard sprinklers (year-round), and have a sense of their output (which I would define the same as @MonicaCellio ), whereas those in the damp East do not.

Comment: @choster I think you could be right about the garden sprinkler, but in my experience a sprinkler delivers at least as much water as a light shower. Do you think it possible that the term 'a sprinkle of rain' predates the garden sprinkler and that the device is named from the natural event?