# What is the word for "Slow raining"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Today in my city, it's raining very slowly. What is this called in English?.

I am from India. In Hindi we say **'Rimjhim'**. What is it called in English?

Comment: See also [What kind of rain is “sprinkles”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50008/what-kind-of-rain-is-sprinkles)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

We use the words "drizzling" or "sprinkling" here.

They both mean "to rain or let fall in fine drops"

If it's very, very light rain, you can use the word "mist". "Drizzling" usually implies a little harder rain than "sprinkling".

Comment: British English doesn't use *sprinkling* as a verb, preferring *spitting* instead. We may have *a* sprinkling of light rain, though.

Comment: It's very common in American English. I've never heard "spitting" to describe rain (never been to Britain either).

Comment: Spitting is used also in New Zealand.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked up the synonyms for *rain* in a thesaurus, like [here](http://thesaurus.com/browse/rain) for example?

The normal answer is *sprinkle* at first, or maybe *drizzle* if it persists or is a bit heavier.